# Basien network with pomegranate

Tags: python, probability, pomegranate

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

----> result = model.predict_proba({'b': None},evidence)

TypeError: BayesianNetwork.predict_proba() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

```py
`from pomegranate.distributions import Categorical  
from pomegranate.distributions import ConditionalCategorical  
from pomegranate.bayesian_network import BayesianNetwork  

b = Categorical(\[\[0.001, 0.999\]\])  
e = Categorical(\[\[0.002, 0.998\]\])  
a = ConditionalCategorical(\[\[\[0.95, 0.05\], \[0.94, 0.06\], \[0.29, 0.71\], \[0.001, 0.999\]\]\])  
j = ConditionalCategorical(\[\[\[0.9, 0.1\], \[0.3, 0.7\]\]\])  
m = ConditionalCategorical(\[\[\[0.7, 0.3\], \[0.1, 0.9\]\]\])  

model = BayesianNetwork(\[b, e, a, j, m\], \[(b, a), (e, a), (a, j), (a, m)\])  

evidence = {'m': 1, 'j': 0}  
result = model.predict_proba({'b': None},evidence)  
probability_b = result\[0\].parameters\[0\]  
print("P(B=1 | M=1, J=0) =", probability_b\[1\])`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.